# grunt setup on windows

Tags: gruntjs, stylus

I'm install grunt on windows 8. My gruntfile.js very simple:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    stylus: {

            files: {
                'build/style.css': ['styles/style.styl'],
            }

    };
    autoprefixer: {

    // prefix the specified file
    single_file: {
      options: {
        // Target-specific options go here.
      }
      src: 'build/style.css';
      dest: 'build/styles.css';
    };
  };

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['stylus']);
    grunt.registerTask('stylus', ['stylus']);
    grunt.registerTask('ap', ['autoprefixer']);
};
```

I'm run grunt and get error:

> > X:\PROJEKTS\MY\test\Gruntfile.js:5
> >                         'build/style.css': ['styles/style.styl']
> >                                          ^ Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
> >
> > > SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Help me please

Answer (score 3):

This is all messed-up, and not even valid javascript :-) - and you are missing an init config.

Start by fixing it:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.config.init({
  stylus: {

        files: {
            'build/style.css': ['styles/style.styl'],
        }

  },
  autoprefixer: {
    // prefix the specified file
    single_file: {
      options: {
        // Target-specific options go here.
      },
      src: 'build/style.css',
      dest: 'build/styles.css'
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['stylus']);
grunt.registerTask('stylus', ['stylus']);
grunt.registerTask('ap', ['autoprefixer']);
};
```